# What happens to the main application thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

As far as I know, there are 3 threads in a Swing GUI application:

- the *main application thread*, which executes the `main()` method
- the *toolkit thread*, which receives the system events
- the *event dispatching thread*, dedicated to the painting and event handling of the GUI stuff

Generally, the main method just makes a call to `SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)` in order to initialize a window and so on, thus the GUI initialization is made on the EDT... BTW, as far as I know (again), everything that touches the GUI must be executed on the EDT...

Questions: What is the *main thread* used / usable for? Does it just die after the call to `invokeLater()`? Does it consume resources? Can I (and is it a good practice to) use it to perform... I don't know... Network stuff?

Comment: I believe the main thread will die if nothing prevents it to return and then only the EDT thread lives. If you have anything else to do in the main, do it there but don't think too much about what you could put there. If there is any user action on your GUI that requires a long task not to be directly displayed, just create a new thread from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread in a Java program dies when control reaches the end of `main()`.

In the program architecture that you describe, the main thread already has created the EDT and maybe other threads by that point, and those other threads keep the JVM alive.

Every thread in Java is either a *daemon* thread, or a non-daemon thread.  The latter is the default case for a new `Thread`.  You have to call `t.setDaemon(true)` if you want a daemon.

A JVM will keep running as long as there is at least one non-daemon thread still alive.

> What is the main thread used / usable for?

It is usable for any purpose that you would use any other thread for.  It executes whatever code you write for it to execute.

Answer (score 2):

A Swing programmer deals, actually, with **3 kinds** of threads:

1. **Initial** threads (the one that executes the initial application code,
   our main here)
2. The **EDT** (as you metioned)
3. **Worker** threads (to deal with background tasks)

The inital thread creates the Runnable to run swings tasks and schedule it in the EDT. After that, the program is primarly driven by the GUI, and the application code survives and can **continue** to execute other tasks (*Network staff as you noticed*) and consumes resources as much as it needs.
Any Swing component method must be invoqued by the EDT (but some of them) because they swing method are not "*thread-safe*". So, 
 `SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)`
 just queues the runnable in the **EDT** task list and wait for its turn to run.

The [doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) is quite helpful.